# how to auto scroll inside recylerview

Tags: android, kotlin, scroll

i have a recyclerview whose item is another recyclerview .when i click the item of outer recyclerview  the items of inner recyclerview will be shown.but when i click the last item of outer recyclerview i have to scroll to see the items of inner recyclerview .i want the items of inner recyclerview  to be auto shown when i click the last item of outer recyclerview .

i have tried smoothScrollToPosition and scrolltoposition on innner recyclerview   but it doesnot work.i am settting the adapter of inner recyclerview   in outter recyclerview  adapter.i am doing this in kotlin for a mobile application .please help me in this case

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.